# Could I get a list of all python errors?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Could I get a list of all python errors?:
How (are there any built in functions) and where (a website maybe) could I do this?

Comment: What's the use case for this?

Comment: This post shows zero effort or research on your part.

Comment: How about [the doc](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html)?

Answer (score 2):

As expected, the [official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html) has the answer.

On this page, you'll find the base exceptions, and the concrete exceptions as well, sorted by category.
You'll find at section [5.4. Exception hierarchy](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#exception-hierarchy) an inheritance tree displaying the hierarchy between built-in exceptions.

The most interesting point certainly is that every exception extends `BaseException`, and that a custom exception should in most cases inherit from `Exception`.

Here is the exceptions hierarchy tree:

```
BaseException
 +-- SystemExit
 +-- KeyboardInterrupt
 +-- GeneratorExit
 +-- Exception
      +-- StopIteration
      +-- StopAsyncIteration
      +-- ArithmeticError
      |    +-- FloatingPointError
      |    +-- OverflowError
      |    +-- ZeroDivisionError
      +-- AssertionError
      +-- AttributeError
      +-- BufferError
      +-- EOFError
      +-- ImportError
      |    +-- ModuleNotFoundError
      +-- LookupError
      |    +-- IndexError
      |    +-- KeyError
      +-- MemoryError
      +-- NameError
      |    +-- UnboundLocalError
      +-- OSError
      |    +-- BlockingIOError
      |    +-- ChildProcessError
      |    +-- ConnectionError
      |    |    +-- BrokenPipeError
      |    |    +-- ConnectionAbortedError
      |    |    +-- ConnectionRefusedError
      |    |    +-- ConnectionResetError
      |    +-- FileExistsError
      |    +-- FileNotFoundError
      |    +-- InterruptedError
      |    +-- IsADirectoryError
      |    +-- NotADirectoryError
      |    +-- PermissionError
      |    +-- ProcessLookupError
      |    +-- TimeoutError
      +-- ReferenceError
      +-- RuntimeError
      |    +-- NotImplementedError
      |    +-- RecursionError
      +-- SyntaxError
      |    +-- IndentationError
      |         +-- TabError
      +-- SystemError
      +-- TypeError
      +-- ValueError
      |    +-- UnicodeError
      |         +-- UnicodeDecodeError
      |         +-- UnicodeEncodeError
      |         +-- UnicodeTranslateError
      +-- Warning
           +-- DeprecationWarning
           +-- PendingDeprecationWarning
           +-- RuntimeWarning
           +-- SyntaxWarning
           +-- UserWarning
           +-- FutureWarning
           +-- ImportWarning
           +-- UnicodeWarning
           +-- BytesWarning
           +-- ResourceWarning
```